# What does span attribute inside <a> tag mean?

Tags: html

I came across some HTML:

```
<div id="div-1">
    <a href="next" span id="next">hidfoli</a>
</div>
```

I want to know what does `span` inside `a` tag mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not mean anything.

It is ignored, except in the sense that browsers still parse the attribute and store it in the DOM (not directly as a property of the element node, but in the `attributes` array).

Answer (score 3):

`span` is a tag, not an `attribute` of any element, so probably that was mistyped and the HTML is invalid.

So either `a` must be nested inside the `span` tag, or `span` must be nested inside the `a` tag, but as far as attribute goes, there is nothing as such.

You can always validate your markup using [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

If you mean that `span` is *NESTED* inside the `a` tag, than I can show you how it can be used.

```
<a href="#"><span>Hello</span></a>
```

Say you have above in your markup, now both the elements are `inline` so designers often nest the elements in such a way to achieve some typography effect say...

```
a {
   color: red;
}

a span {
   color: green;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/anY7w/)

Or he wants the two words on different lines, so he can do something like

```
a span {
   display: block;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/anY7w/1/)

So it can be used in various scenarios but as far as your syntax goes, it's completely invalid.

---

Just some more information over attributes, if you want to define custom attributes, for some or the other reason, you can create them by prefixing their names using [`data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), and this is valid in HTML5 so the above can be written as `<a href="next" data-span="whatever" id="next">hidfoli</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

The example contains invalid html, it should be:

```
<a href="next"><span id="next">hidfoli</span></a>
```

In general a `span` is used to wrap text so that specific styling may be applied.  More specifically as stated by the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span):

> The HTML  element is a generic inline container for phrasing
>   content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used
>   to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id
>   attributes), or because they share attribute values, such as lang. It
>   should be used only when no other semantic element is appropriate.
>    is very much like a  element, but  is a block-level
>   element whereas a  is an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mistake to me, it probably meant:

```
<a href="next"><span id="next">hidfoli</span></a>
```

Playing a little bit detective, the author probably put a span with id inside the  to be able to access 'hidfoli' string, then realized mid-way that he could put the id right on the  and thus ending up with a faulty html code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `html` code is invalid html...`span` is html tag which can be placed inside `a` tag not as attribute of `a` tag.

correct way

```
<a href="next" id="next"><span>hidfoli</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Span is a HTML tag its not an attribute this is incorrect.

may be like this

```
<a href="next"><span id="next">hidfoli</span></a>
```

but will be same as

```
<a href="next">hidfoli</a>
```

Using the first one not required just for giving text may be used for styling purposes.

Or if you are going to give attributes to nested objects like

```
a span                       $('a span') in Jquery
{
}           in css or
```